# PHP PCRE allow nested patterns (recursion) in a string

Tags: php, regex, recursion, pcre

I got a string like `1(8()3(6()7())9()3())2(4())3()1(0()3())` which is representing a tree.
A bracket appears, if we go one level deeper. Numbers on the same level are neighbours.

Now want to add nodes, for example I want to add a `5` to every path where we have a `1` on the first and a `3` on the second level, so I want to put a `5()` after every `3(` which is inside of a `1(`.
So `5()`has to be added 3 times and the result should be `1(8()3(5()6()7())9()3(5()))2(4())3()1(0()3(5()))`

The Problem is, that I don't get the code working with the PCRE recursion. If I match a tree representation string without and fixed paths like `1(` and `3(` it works, but when I generate a regex with those fixed patterns, it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/plain;utf-8');

$node = [1, 3, 5];
$path = '1(8()3(6()7())9()3())2(4())3()1(0()3())';

echo $path.'
';

$nes = '\((((?>[^()]+)|(?R))*)\)';
$nes = '('.$nes.')*';

echo preg_match('/'.$nes.'/x', $path) ? 'matches' : 'matches not';
echo '
';

// creates a regex with the fixed path structure, but allows nested elements in between
// in this example something like: /^anyNestedElementsHere 1( anyNestedElementsHere 3( anyNestedElementsHere ))/
$re = $nes;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($node)-1; $i++) {
    $re .= $node[$i].'\(';
    if ($i != count($node)-2)
        $re .= $nes;
}
$re = '/^('.$re.')/x';

echo str_replace($nes, '   '.$nes.'   ', $re).'
';
echo preg_match($re, $path) ? 'matches' : 'matches not';
echo '
';
// append 5()
echo preg_replace($re, '${1}'.$node[count($node)-1].'()', $path);
?>
```

And this is the output, where you can see how the generated regex looks like:

```
1(8()3(6()7())9()3())2(4())3()1(0()3())
matches
/^(   (\((((?>[^()]+)|(?R))*)\))*   1\(   (\((((?>[^()]+)|(?R))*)\))*   3\()/x
matches not
1(8()3(6()7())9()3())2(4())3()1(0()3())
```

I hope you understand my problem and hope you can tell me, where my error is.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

**Regex**

The following regex matches nested brackets recursively, finding an opening `1(` on the first level, and an opening `3(` on the second level (as a direct child). It also attempts successive matches, either on the same level or going down the respective levels to find another match.

```
~
(?(?=\A)  # IF: First match attempt (if at start of string)   - -

  # we are on 1st level => find next "1("

  (?<balanced_brackets>
    # consumes balanced brackets recursively where there is no match
    [^()]*+
    \(  (?&balanced_brackets)*?  \)
  )*?

  # match "1(" => enter level 2
  1\(

|         # ELSE: Successive matches  - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

  \G    # Start at end of last match (level 3)

  # Go down to level 2 - match ")"
  (?&balanced_brackets)*?
  \)

  # or go back to level 1 - matching another ")"
  (?>
    (?&balanced_brackets)*?
    \)
    
    # and enter level 2 again
    (?&balanced_brackets)*?
    1\(
  )*?
)                                      # - - - - - - - - - - - -

# we are on level 2 => consume balanced brackets and match "3("
(?&balanced_brackets)*?
3\K\(  # also reset the start of the match
~x
```

**Replacement**

```
(5()
```

**Text**

```
Input:
1(8()3(6()7())9()3())2(4())3()1(0()3())

Output:
1(8()3(5()6()7())9()3(5()))2(4())3()1(0()3(5()))
       ^^^            ^^^                  ^^^
       [1]            [2]                  [3]
```

<kbd>[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/mT6fE4/1)</kbd>

---

### How it works

**We start** by using a [`conditional subpattern`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) to distinguish between:

- the first match attempt (from level 1) and
- the successive attempts (starting at level 3, anchored with the [`\G assertion`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html)).

```
(?(?=\A)  # IF followed by start of string
    # This is the first attempt
|         # ELSE
    # This is another attempt
    \G    # and we'll anchor it to the end of last match
)
```

**For the first match**, we'll consume all nested brackets that don't match `1(`, in order to get the cursor to a position in the first level where it could find a successful match.

- This is a well-known recursive pattern to match nested constructs. If you're unfamiliar with it, please refer to [`Recursion`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) and [`Subroutines`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html).

```
(?<balanced_brackets>        # ANY NUMBER OF BALANCED BRACKETS
  [^()]*+                    # match any characters 
  \(                         # opening bracket
    (?&balanced_brackets)*?  #  with nested bracket (recursively)
  \)                         # closing bracket in the main level
)*?                          # Repeated any times (lazy)
```

Notice this is a [`named group`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) that we will use as a subroutine call many times in the pattern to consume unwanted balanced brackets, as `(?&balanced_brackets)*?`.

**Next levels**. Now, to enter level 2, we need to match:

```
1\(
```

And finally, we'll consume any balanced brackets until we find the opening of the 3rd level:

```
(?&balanced_brackets)*?
3\(
```

That's it. We've just matched our first occurrence, so we can insert the replacement text in that position.

**Next match**. For the successive match attempts, we can either:

- go down to level 2 matching a closing `)` to find another occurrence of `3(`
- go further down to level 1 matching 2 closing `)` and, from there, match using the same strategy as we used for the first match.

This is achieved with the following subpattern:

```
\G                             # anchored to the end of last match (level 3)
(?&balanced_brackets)*?        # consume any balanced brackets
\)                             # go down to level 2
                               #
(?>                            # And optionally
  (?&balanced_brackets)*?      #   consume level 2 brackets
  \)                           #   to go down to level 1
  (?&balanced_brackets)*?      #   consume level 1 brackets
  1\(                          #   and go up to level 2 again
)*?                            # As many times as it needs to (lazy)
```

**To conclude**, we can match the opening of the 3rd level:

```
(?&balanced_brackets)*?
3\(
```

We'll also [reset the start of match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) near the end of the pattern, with [`\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html), to only match the last opening bracket. Thus, we can simply replace with `(5()`, avoiding the use of backreferences.

---

#### PHP Code

We only need to call **[`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)** with the same values used above.

<kbd>[Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/OhvMW2)</kbd>

---

**Why did your regex fail?**

Since you asked, the pattern is anchored to the start of string. It can only match the first occurrence.

```
/^(   (\((((?>[^()]+)|(?R))*)\))*   1\(   (\((((?>[^()]+)|(?R))*)\))*   3\()/x
```

Also, it doesn't match the first occurrence because the construct `(?R)` recurses the the *whole* pattern (trying to match `^` again). We could change `(?R)` to `(?2)`.

The main reason, though, is because it is not consuming the characters before any opening `\(`. For example:

```
Input:
1(8()3(6()7())9()3())2(4())3()1(0()3())
  ^
  #this "8" can't be consumed with the pattern
```

There's also a behaviour that should be considered: [PCRE treats recursion as atomic](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recursebacktrack.html). So you have to make sure that the pattern will consume unwanted brackets as in the above example, but also avoid matching `1(` or `3(` in their respective levels.

Answer (score 1):

I'd break down this problem into two smaller parts:

First, extract the `1` nodes, using the following regex:

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<tree>
    (?: \d+ \( (?&tree) \) )*
  )
)
\b 1 \( (?&tree) \)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iG2bT4/4)

Use `preg_replace_callback` for this. This will match `1(8()3(6()7())9()3())` and `1(0()3())`.

Next, it's just a matter of replacing `3(` with `3(5()` and you're done.

Example in PHP:

```php
$path = '1(8()3(6()7())9()3())2(4())3()1(0()3())';

$path = preg_replace_callback('#
    (?(DEFINE)
      (?<tree>
        (?: \d+ \( (?&tree) \) )*
      )
    )
    \b 1 \( (?&tree) \)
#x', function($m) {
    return str_replace('3(', '3(5()', $m[0]);
}, $path);
```

The result is: `1(8()3(5()6()7())9()3(5()))2(4())3()1(0()3(5()))`

Comment: Neat answer! There's a detail to be checked if you feel like revising: `str_replace` does not guarantee `3()` is a direct child of `1()`, [e.g. `1(2(3()))`](http://ideone.com/5DZMcm)

Comment: @Mariano hmm that's how I understood the question (`3` as a descendant of `1` - not necessarily a direct one), but I may be wrong. OP should clarify. Have a +1 for a very detailed answer ;)

Comment: You're right. It could be interpreted either way. Let's wait for clarification.